# How does the cursor limit effect the Tableau data extraction

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I am trying to create an extract in `Tableau Desktop 8.2` with Amazon Redshift (DB) 
but i get this error

ERROR: exceeded the maximum size allowed for the result set of a cursor operation. current size: "67407708716". analyze the current configuration via stv_cursor_configuration, and consider increasing the value of the max_cursor_result_set_size configuration parameter.;
Error while executing the query

Unable to create extract
ERROR: exceeded the maximum size allowed for the result set of a cursor operation. current size: "67407708716". analyze the current configuration via stv_cursor_configuration, and consider increasing the value of the max_cursor_result_set_size configuration parameter.;
Error while executing the query

Can somebody guide me on this?

Our service team increased the Cursor limit after i state the Issue.

Comment: ...so what do you need help with? Are you saying now that after you made the corrections to your configuration, you are still getting the same error?

Comment: Check if this table has a BLOB or a large text field. In Tableau, instead to link table try with `select only_needed_columns`.

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114, have you solved it?

Comment: @danihp : yes the `Custom sql query` is used and in select no large text fields are there.. some issue with our `Redshift DW`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Redshift concurrent-cursor limit is exceeded during a background refresh task. You can simply turn off `UseDeclareFetch` in a data source customisation or limit the concurrent extracts jobs by putting them into a single schedule.

See Tableau KB regarding Redshift Cursor issues:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/redshift-concurrent-cursor-limit